# Using .config/directory as a git repo

Tags: git, symlink, git-commit, git-add, hardlink

The whole configuration for a soft is located in `.config/soft`. 
Lately, I had an idea to practice basic git usage by initializing a git repo to which I would send commits with config changes.

My question is that I am not sure if I should initialize `.config/soft` as a git repo. I thought about initializing it somewhere like Projects/soft and linking directory or specific files from `.config/soft` to it.

What's the best solution here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+track+home+directory

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that I am not sure if I should initialize `.config/soft` as a git repo.

If you want it as new repository you can use `git submodules`

[image]